# Is this approach of calculating mutual induction from magnetic flux Ok?

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Coursework from Khan Academy, Electromagnetic Induction, - Mutual Induction worked example. For context video link - [Mutual Induction Worked Example Link](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/in-in-class-12th-physics-india/in-in-electromagnetic-induction/x51bd77206da864f3:mutual-inductance/v/worked-example-mutual-inductance-emi-physics-khan-academy)

Doubt link: - [Image of the solved question from the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T46se.jpg)

In the video, the instructor solved the problem by saying that the amount of magnetic field lines passing through the top loop, is more in the second case.

I used the equation,

$$-M_{12} \left(\frac{d}{dt(i_2)}\right) = -N\left(\frac{d}{dt( Φ_B )}\right)$$

So, in the second case $Φ_B$ is more since,

$$BA \ cos \ θ = Φ_B$$

and $θ = 0$ degrees in second case and $θ = 90$ degrees in first case. (Which means there is no magnetic flux in 1st case, is that possible?)

So, we can say, value of $M$ will also be more in the second case. Is this approach ok?

Here is the link to how I tried solving it, [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPOAd.jpg)

Is this ok? I am getting the same answer as the video but since the approach is different, I want to make sure there is nothing wrong with my concepts, and if it's wrong, can you please provide a mathematical solution that's not too complicated? Would really appreciate that.